# How to render all IE version with w3c box model?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser, internet-explorer

How to render all IE version with w3c box model?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you please rephrase it, and maybe provide some examples?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120273/make-a-divs-total-width-the-same-in-both-strict-and-quirks-mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

For IE6 and newer, use a Doctype that triggers [Standards (AKA Strict) Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

HTML 4.01 Strict is usually a good bet.

IE5.5/Win32 and lower just don't support the standard box model.

Comment: does IE 8 render according to W3C Box model?

Comment: Only if it is in IE7Compat + Standards mode or IE8 mode. It doesn't in IE7Compat + Quirks mode.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Every version of Internet Explorer since 5.5 will render using the W3C Box Model *if* you tell IE that you want it to do so. Otherwise IE5.5 will continue to render your web-site using the Netscape box model - as to not break your existing web-sites.